# Settings contains a dot which is not supported, but module gets enabled properly

Tags: 8, debugging, configuration

I'm developing a search engine module for Drupal 8.

On a clean new Drupal website, I can install it from the admin GUI, but when I enable it I have the classical white screen (`The website encountered an error ...`).
Checking the `error.log` yields the following :

> Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigValueException: "gref.settings key contains a dot which is not supported." at /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/ConfigBase.php line 211, referer: http://10.113.101.197/admin/modules

But, if I go back to the website, the module is installed properly, and no further issue is reported (even when uninstalling the module).

Here is my configuration :

```
- config
  - install
     - views.view.grefsearch.yml
     - search_api.server.grefserver.yml
     - search_api.index.grefindex.yml
     - gref.settings.yml
     - gref.schema.yml
     - facets.facet.grefother.yml
     - block.block.gref.yml
```

And here is gref.settings.yml

```
gref:
  page_title: 'Gref Search'
  source_text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
```

Any ideas why I have this error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, classical scenario, 30 seconds after I open a bounty for the question, I find the answer myself ...

I was looking into the wrong file. I started the skeleton of my module by following [this tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/a-practical-guide-to-building-basic-drupal-8-modules).

In the ["Basic Structure"](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/basic-structure) section of the tutorial, dots are used in keys for the `.schema.yml` file. It is actually forbidden to use that, but the tutorial said you could anyway.

```
/config/schema/loremipsum.schema.yml :

loremipsum.settings:
  type: config_object
  label: 'Lorem Ipsum settings'
  mapping:
    loremipsum:
      type: mapping
      mapping:
        page_title:
          type: text
          label: 'Lorem ipsum generator page title:'
        source_text:
          type: text
          label: 'Source text for lorem ipsum generation:'
```

I removed the dot at the key, and the problem disappeared.

Comment: What dot at the key did you remove? loremipsum(dot)settings?

Comment: Yes, I think it was the dot between `loremipsum` and `settings`.